# How do i store my loop outputs dynamically?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to run a sensitivity study for my script. I have 3 main variables **(velocity, searchVolume1, and searchVolume2)** that would be changing in the code. However, I have been able to write a script that only allows for one of the variables (searchVolume1) to change while the other two are kept constant. I now would want the script to allow two variables (searchvolume1 and velocity) to change instead, and afterwards, I would do the re-runs where the entire procedure will be repeated with the third variable (searchVolume2) changed. Where only one variable is changed, the script that works is:

```
searchVolume1 = [0.5, 0.5, 2.4, 3.7, 4.6, 5.1]';
for kk = 1: numel(searchVolume1)

    [xN, xU, xC] = myMfile_sensitivity(searchVolume, kk);

    t1(:,kk)  = xN(:,kk);
    t2(:,kk)  = xU(:,kk);
    t3(:,kk)  = xC(:,kk);    
end
```

I have re-edited this (see below) to include a second variable change. Although I am thinking of creating a kind of dynamic storage, I am however not exactly sure what to do to store the results for t1, t2, and t3 with the new changes.

```
Velocity = [10, 20, 30];
searchVolume1 = [0.5, 0.5, 2.4, 3.7, 4.6, 5.1]';

for tt = 1: numel(velocity)
   for kk = 1: numel(searchVolume1)

     [xN, xU, xC] = myMfile_sensitivity(searchVolume, kk, velocity, tt);

     t1(:,kk)  = xN(:,kk);
     t2(:,kk)  = xU(:,kk);
     t3(:,kk)  = xC(:,kk);    
   end
end
```

The above implies that I’m supposed to have: `t1, t2, t3` for all `searchVolume1` of the 3 `velocities`. Please, any idea/help/suggestions is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: a) don't grow arrays inside loops, ***preallcoate*** them to save time. b) look into multi-dimensional arrays, structures or cells and store in a sensible manner.

Comment: What is the size of xN, xU, and xC? Are they just numbers or are they arrays?

Answer (score 0):

As Adriaan said, you want to preallocate the output variable sizes to speed things up. I assumed that xN, xU, and xC are constants. Instead of passing the entire arrays and the index to myMfile_sensitivity, I changed it so simply the number you want is passed (e.g., searchVolume1(kk)).

```
velocity = [10, 20, 30];
searchVolume1 = [0.5, 0.5, 2.4, 3.7, 4.6, 5.1]';
% I just copied searchVolume1 for this example
searchVolume2 = [0.5, 0.5, 2.4, 3.7, 4.6, 5.1]';

t1 = zeros((length(velocity),length(searchVolume1),length(searchVolume2));
t2 = zeros((length(velocity),length(searchVolume1),length(searchVolume2));
t3 = zeros((length(velocity),length(searchVolume1),length(searchVolume2));
for tt = 1: numel(velocity)
   for kk = 1: numel(searchVolume1)
       for jj = 1: numel(searchVolume2)

           [xN, xU, xC] = myMfile_sensitivity(searchVolume1(kk), velocity(tt), searchVolume2(jj));

           t1(tt,kk,jj)  = xN;
           t2(tt,kk,jj)  = xU;
           t3(tt,kk,jj)  = xC;    
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the lengths for any `searchVolume1` is the same for any `velocity` but isn't the same when velocity is changed. for instance, the lengths for any `searchVolume1 = 28` when `velocity = 10`. However, when velocity  changes to 20, the length of searchVolume1 becomes 44.

Comment: When i run the current solution, there is an internal error in the main script `"myMfile_sensitivity"`. However, i would also want to believe that the statement i've made above should as well affect your solution?. Thanks for your help @Jeff Lapierre

Comment: The lengths of velocity and searchVolume1+2 should not matter for this code. The reason you are getting an error on 'myMfile_sensitivity' is because you made it seem like that was a function that you had wrote. I don't know what that function is suppose to do. That would probably be a different question from this one.

Comment: Oh i see! editing the original M-file is a big call because it is quite a heavy code. Instead of trying to fix the original script I'm guessing i'd rather utilize the time i have on the already working code (keeping `velocity` and `searchVolume2` as constants while i change only `searchVolume1`) . Many thanks for your help @Jeff Lapierre.